# I have to input IFERROR into an if function so it spits out that Instrument is not listed, . Im not sure why its not calculating it correctly

Tags: excel, if-statement

This is the original given formula:

```
=IF(E3=3,VLOOKUP(H3,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('Rental Data'!H3,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,3,FALSE))
```

and this is what i did:

```
=IFERROR(IF(E2=3,VLOOKUP(H2,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('Rental Data'!H2,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,3,FALSE),"Instrument not listed"))
```

but it is showing that i've inputted too many arguments.

Comment: your `)` on the end are incorrect: `=IFERROR(IF(E2=3,VLOOKUP(H2,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('Rental Data'!H2,'Rental Information'!$A$3:$D$7,3,FALSE)),"Instrument not listed")`

Comment: i also realized i forgot to input a ,  and the ) at the end was correct :)